# Strange 'MySqlSiteMapProvider' error although 'XmlSiteMapProvider' is being used

Tags: c#, web-config, iis-8, sitemapprovider

I've recently migrated a few web applications from a shared hosting environment to my dedicated server. The server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and all my sites (all slight variations on the same C# web application) work fine however one of the sites is throwing this error when you try to browse to a page.

```
Server Error in 'ABC' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Host 'SERVERNAME' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Source Error: 


Line 283:    <siteMap>
Line 284:      <providers>
Line 285:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 286:      </providers>
Line 287:    </siteMap>

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 285 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2053.0
```

What's strange is that I'm using `System.Web.XMLSiteMapProvider` and not a MySQL provider (as the error seems to suggest), see below from `web.config`

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="Admin" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/Admin.sitemap" />
    <add name="Branch" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/Branch.sitemap" />
    <add name="Supplier" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/web.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

There are two other versions of the same application (BETA & a clone) both work fine and their `web.config` files have the same sitemap providers. Why would this error be thrown and what does it relate to? Did I miss something when setting up IIS?

Comment: Note that the error is coming from the `machine.config`, not your `web.config`. Try adding a `<clear/>` to the `web.config` provider list to ensure you're only using the ones you specify.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidG - should I add this before or after my XmlSiteMap provider entries?

Comment: Before yours as they are done in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the error is coming from the `machine.config`, not the `web.config`. All `web.config` files essentially inherit from the basic machine version. To override the providers, you can simply clear the list first. For example:

```xml
<siteMap defaultProvider="Admin">
  <providers>
    <!-- Add this next line: -->
    <clear/>
    <add name="Admin" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/Admin.sitemap" />
    <add name="Branch" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/Branch.sitemap" />
    <add name="Supplier" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/MenuSystem/web.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it threw another error (no defaultProvider specified) - can you update your answer to include a defaultProvider for users who may find the same issue?

Comment: OK, I've added that for you.